# ConfigureAwait(false) vs setting sync context to null

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I often see recommended for async library code, that we should use `ConfigureAwait(false)` on all async calls to avoid situations where the return of our call will be scheduled on a UI thread or a web request synchronization context  causing issues with deadlocks among other things.

One of the problems with using `ConfigureAwait(false)` is that it isn't something you can just do on the entry point of your library call. In order for it to be effective it must be done all the way down the stack throughout your library code.

It seems to me that a viable alternative is to simply set the current synchronization context to null at the top-level public-facing entry points of the library, and just forget about `ConfigureAwait(false)`. However, I don't see many instances of people taking or recommending this approach.

Is there anything wrong with simply setting the current synchronization context to null on the library entry points? Are there any potential problems with this approach (other than the possible insignificant performance hit of having the await post to the default synchronization context)?

(EDIT #1) Adding some example code of what I mean:

```
   public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new LoggingSynchronizationContext(1));

            Console.WriteLine("Executing library code that internally clears synchronization context");
            //First try with clearing the context INSIDE the lib
            RunTest(true).Wait();
            //Here we again have the context intact
            Console.WriteLine($"After First Call Context in Main Method is {SynchronizationContext.Current?.ToString()}");


            Console.WriteLine("\nExecuting library code that does NOT internally clear the synchronization context");
            RunTest(false).Wait();
            //Here we again have the context intact
            Console.WriteLine($"After Second Call Context in Main Method is {SynchronizationContext.Current?.ToString()}");

        }

        public async static Task RunTest(bool clearContext)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Before Lib call our context is {SynchronizationContext.Current?.ToString()}");
            await DoSomeLibraryCode(clearContext);
            //The rest of this method will get posted to my LoggingSynchronizationContext

            //But.......
            if(SynchronizationContext.Current == null){
                //Note this will always be null regardless of whether we cleared it or not
                Console.WriteLine("We don't have a current context set after return from async/await");
            }
        }


        public static async Task DoSomeLibraryCode(bool shouldClearContext)
        {
            if(shouldClearContext){
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);
            }
            await DelayABit();
            //The rest of this method will be invoked on the default (null) synchronization context if we elected to clear the context
            //Or it should post to the original context otherwise
            Console.WriteLine("Finishing library call");
        }

        public static Task DelayABit()
        {
            return Task.Delay(1000);
        }

    }

    public class LoggingSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
    {

        readonly int contextId;
        public LoggingSynchronizationContext(int contextId)
        {
            this.contextId = contextId;
        }
        public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"POST TO Synchronization Context (ID:{contextId})");
            base.Post(d, state);
        }

        public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Post Synchronization Context (ID:{contextId})");
            base.Send(d, state);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Context (ID:{contextId})";
        }
    }
```

The execution of this will output:

```
Executing library code that internally clears synchronization context
Before Lib call our context is Context (ID:1) 
Finishing library call 
POST TO Synchronization Context (ID:1)
We don't have a current context set after return from async/await
After First Call Context in Main Method is Context (ID:1)

Executing library code that does NOT internally clear the synchronization context 
Before Lib call our context is Context (ID:1) POST TO Synchronization Context (ID:1) 
Finishing library call
POST TO Synchronization Context (ID:1) 
We don't have a current context set after return from async/await
After Second Call Context in Main Method is Context (ID:1)
```

This all works like I would expect, but I don't come across people recommending libraries do this internally. I find that requiring every internal await point be called with `ConfigureAwait(false)` is annoying, and even one missed `ConfigureAwait()` can cause trouble throughout an application. This seems like it would solve the issue simply at the public entry-point of the library with a single line of code. What am I missing?

(EDIT #2)

Based on some feedback from Alexei's answer,  it seems I hadn't consider the possibility of a task not being immediately awaited. Since the execution context is captured at the time of the await (not the time of the async call), that would mean the change to `SynchronizationContext.Current` would not be isolated to the library method. Based on this it would seem that it should suffice to force a capture of the context by wrapping the internal logic of the library in a call that forces an wait. For example:

```
    async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var getStringTask = GetStringFromMyLibAsync();
        this.textBox1.Text = await getStringTask;
    }

    async Task<string> GetStringFromMyLibInternal()
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return "HELLO WORLD";
    }

    async Task<string> GetStringFromMyLibAsync()
    {
        //This forces a capture of the current execution context (before synchronization context is nulled
        //This means the caller's context should be intact upon return
        //even if not immediately awaited.
        return await GetStringFromMyLibInternal();          
    }
```

(EDIT #3)

Based on the discussion on Stephen Cleary's answer. There are some problems with this approach. But we can do a similar approach by wrapping the library call in a non-async method that still returns a task, but takes care of resetting the syncrhonization context at the end. (Note this uses the SynchronizationContextSwitcher from Stephen's AsyncEx library.

```
    async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var getStringTask = GetStringFromMyLibAsync();
        this.textBox1.Text = await getStringTask;
    }

    async Task<string> GetStringFromMyLibInternal()
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return "HELLO WORLD";
    }

    Task<string> GetStringFromMyLibAsync()
    {
        using (SynchronizationContextSwitcher.NoContext())
        {
            return GetStringFromMyLibInternal();          
        } 
        //Context will be restored by the time this method returns its task.
    }
```

Comment: If you can show that *correctly* sets and restores context (in particular at the moment code returns as part of `await` in your library method) this question would be much better... Also I suspect you'll get your answer by the time you are done trying to write such code :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. As far as I understand, Synchronization context is captured but NOT restored at await points. It is simply used by the awaiter to post the continuation delegate, but if you were to do `SynchronizationContext.Current` right after an await it would always be null (unless the context itself does something to restore itself).

Comment: You do understand that your proposal reads like you want to change current thread's synchronization context (i.e. from UI to `null`) and not restore it thus making all *other* calls not related to your library to use `null` context after call to your library (unless caller explicitly protects they  context with `await` which is not requirement).

Comment: I updated my question with example code that shows what I mean. Hopefully it is more clear. The more I think about it the less I can see a downside (even a performance downside) to this. But I want someone with more experience then me to validate this approach before I use it on a larger scale.

Comment: The `SynchronizationContext` is captured at the call site, so the caller of my library will still have the control of the synchronization context their await will use to execute the continuation after the return  from the lib code. I'm only modifying the `SynchronizationContext` within my lib.

Comment: I've added code as answer - you seem to expect every `async` call to be immediately `await`-ed, but it is not the case. I.e. standard way of running code in parallel is to collect tasks first and than `await` wit h`WhenAll`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I often see recommended for async library code, that we should use ConfigureAwait(false) on all async calls to avoid situations where the return of our call will be scheduled on a UI thread or a web request synchronization context causing issues with deadlocks among other things.

I recommend `ConfigureAwait(false)` because it (correctly) notes that the calling context is not required. It also gives you a small performance benefit. While `ConfigureAwait(false)` can prevent deadlocks, that is ***not*** its intended purpose.

> It seems to me that a viable alternative is to simply set the current synchronization context to null at the top-level public-facing entry points of the library, and just forget about ConfigureAwait(false).

Yes, that is an option. It won't completely avoid deadlocks, though, because [`await` will attempt to resume on `TaskScheduler.Current` if there's no current `SynchronizationContext`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Also, it feels wrong to have a library replacing a framework-level component.

But you can do this if you want. Just don't forget to set it back to its original value at the end.

Oh, one other pitfall: there are APIs out there that will *assume* the current SyncCtx is what's provided for that framework. Some ASP.NET helper APIs are like that. So, if you call back end-user code, then that could be a problem. But in that case, you should explicitly document what context their callbacks are invoked in anyway.

> However, I don't see many instances of people taking or recommending this approach.

It is slowly becoming more popular. Enough so that I've added [an API for this in my AsyncEx library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx.Tasks/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/SynchronizationContextSwitcher.cs):

```
using (SynchronizationContextSwitcher.NoContext())
{
  ...
}
```

I haven't used this technique myself, though.

> Are there any potential problems with this approach (other than the possible insignificant performance hit of having the await post to the default synchronization context)?

Actually, it's an insignificant performance *gain*.

Comment: Side note: since "calling context" includes current culture for ASP.Net most people don't realize how much they code relies on it. Indeed correctly written code will pass all context along the call in a way that is independent from synchronization context, but such code is rare...

Comment: With regards to a library replacing a framework-level component. It is my understanding from tests I've conducted that if written properly this change would be automatically reverted upon return from the library call (provided there's at least one async/await point between before the context is set to null (see EDIT #2) on the question. Is my interpretation of how this could work incorrect?

Comment: @dtabuenc: The `await` approach of restoring SyncCtx is problematic in a couple of ways: 1) The wrapper method "clearly" doesn't need the context, so it's likely that a future dev would add a `ConfigureAwait(false)` as a best practice. 2) The SyncCtx would only be restored if the task is not yet complete - e.g., a cached response would cause the calling code to lose the SyncCtx.

Comment: Ok so based on this dicussion, if I wanted to achieve my goal of not having to put `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere (or if I want to wrap an existing misbehaving library without having to do `Task.Run`. It sounds like I just need my wrapper to return a task but not be an async method, and use something like the `using(SynchornizationContextSwitcher.NoContext())` around the call to the actual library method. (e.g `return ActualAsyncLibraryCall()`)

Comment: Very interesting alternative approach here: [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2017/02/07/alternative-to-configure-await-false-everywhere/](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2017/02/07/alternative-to-configure-await-false-everywhere/)

Comment: Corrected link from the last comment of @StephenCleary: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2017/02/09/an-alternative-to-configureawaitfalse-everywhere/

Comment: You write that setting the SyncContext "won't completely avoid deadlocks" because "await will attempt to resume on TaskScheduler.Current if there's no current SynchronizationContext".
If the TaskScheduler.Current is the ThreadPoolTaskScheduler how can deadlocks still occur? or perhaps they won't happen with the ThreadPoolTaskScheduler and you mean if it was set to some other TaskScheduler?

Comment: @BornToCode: Yes, I meant if it was set to some other `TaskScheduler`, like [one of these](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/04/04/a-tour-of-parallelextensionsextras/).

Answer (score 1):

Synchronization Context is *similar* to static variable and changing it without restoring before control leaves your method will lead to unexpected behavior.

I don't believe you can safely set current thread's synchronization context inside library function that `await` anything as restoring context in the middle of compiler generated code is not really possible to my knowledge.

Sample:

```
 async Task<int> MyLibraryMethodAsync()
 {
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(....);
    await SomeInnerMethod(); // note that method returns at this point

    // maybe restore synchronization context here...
    return 42;
 }

 ...
 // code that uses library, runs on UI thread

 void async OnButtonClick(...)
 {
    // <-- context here is UI-context, code running on UI thread
    Task<int> doSomething = MyLibraryMethodAsync(); 
    // <-- context here is set by MyLibraryMethod - i.e. null, code running on UI thread
    var textFromFastService = await FastAsync();
    // <-- context here is set by MyLibraryMethod, code running on pool thread (non-UI)
    textBox7.Text = textFromFastService; // fails...

    var get42 = await doSomething;
}
```

Comment: Very interesting. This is definitely something that I had not considered. I have updated my question with a potential work-around for this situation.