# Avoid async from spreading in method signatures

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

What prevents me from constantly using the async/wait pattern in my .net code is that once you create an async method the async keyword tends to spread thru my code forcing me to make all methods async. Is there a pattern to stop this efficiently?

Comment: Yes, not using await/async.

Comment: generally its 'async all the way down'.  Why do you *not* want part of your application to be async?

Comment: void - just don't return anything from an async method...

Comment: Async should be used everywhere it makes sense. If you are not going to do any asynchronous work, why would you mark it async? Nobody forces you to do everything async, just, well, asynchronous tasks.

Comment: @jHilscher `async void` should only be used for UI event handlers. It can cause deadlocks if used elsewhere

Comment: Clearly nobody forces anyone to use async/wait but if you read articles like https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-conclusion.html by Stephen Cleary it seems that when writing new code you should avoid using `Thread`, `ThreadPool` and `BackgroundWorker` in favor of `Task.Run`.

Comment: @JLevett It's not going to cause deadlocks, rather, the callers will have no way of knowing when the operation finishes, or what the result is, and so will continue on before it is done.

Comment: Yes, it's better to async all the way down instead of creating some threads by hand. Moreover, `await` do restore the calling context by default, so you can call some UI-related methods after async operation. So what's your question?

Answer (score 3):

> What prevents me from constantly using the async/wait pattern in my .net code is that once you create an async method the async keyword tends to spread thru my code forcing me to make all methods async. Is there a pattern to stop this efficiently?

Let me ask you this, then: why are you using `async`/`await`? You need to take a step back and decide if you want the benefits of asynchronous code. If you do want those benefits, then your code must be asynchronous. **As soon as you block a thread, you lose all the benefits of async.** So really, why use asynchronous code at all, if you're just going to block a thread anyway?

That said, there are some scenarios where a partially-`async` stack makes sense. For example, if your code base is **temporarily** in a transition state. In this case, you can use one of the hacks described in my article on [brownfield async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx):

- Blocking directly (may cause deadlocks).
- Blocking on a thread pool thread (executes code on a different thread and different context, may cause unexpected parallelism).
- Blocking on the current thread with a thread pool context (executes code in a different context, may cause unexpected parallelism).
- Blocking on a thread with a single-threaded context (executes code on a different thread and different context).
- Blocking on a nested message loop (may cause unexpected reentrancy).

All of these are hacks, and all have different drawbacks. There is no hack that works in every scenario.

Comment: Perfect question. I would say that most of the times I don't really need async, I only need concurrent work threads and I'm always temped by async feeling it is a more efficient approach to achieve the same result. Is async a more efficient approach to multi-threading?

Comment: Async is totally different than multithreading. Async is all about using *fewer* threads, not *more* threads.

Answer (score 0):

As commented earlier you should go async all the way... 
In some cases we use a litle helper class to cut off the async pattern. This class alows you to wait for the result without ending up with a deadlock by replacing the SynchronizationContext.

```
public class NoSynchronizationContextScope : IDisposable
{
    private readonly SynchronizationContext synchronizationContext;

    public NoSynchronizationContextScope()
    {
        synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);
    }

    public void Dispose() => SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(synchronizationContext);
}

void fn() 
{
   using (new NoSynchronizationContextScope())
   {
       fnAsync().Wait();
       // or 
       // var result = fnAsync().Result(); 
       // in case you have to wait for a result
   }
}
```

Comment: There's some further discussion regarding this solution over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41776399/configureawaitfalse-vs-setting-sync-context-to-null

Comment: If you don't want the synchronization context, use `ConfigureAwait(false)`. It's NOT the synchronization context that caused deadlocks, it's buggy coding like calling `.Wait()` or `.Result`

Answer (score 0):

In the very particular case of a method that you want to start running but not wait for the result of (i.e. triggering an event handler) you can use async void. Just make sure you catch all the errors at that point:

```
public async void DoSomething() {
    try {
        var o = await DoThing1();
        await DoThing2(o);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log the error somewhere (to a file, database, etc.)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use async method and invoke not async method in task so outer method will behave like async and inner method is still sync.

```
public async Task OuterFuncAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() => InnerFunc());
}
```

Comment: As I understand the question, OP wants the opposite.