# Migration to async await query

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, deadlock

I am looking to migrate from using the Task Continue pattern to using async await

However this will have to be a transitional migration so I want to be able to do it over time if possible

The pattern I use at the moment is as follows

I have a ViewModel into which is injected a model wrapper, in turn the Model class is injected into the ModelWrapper. 
The purpose of the ModelWrapper is to start a task which performs the functionality contained in the Model in a separate thread

View Model - Calls ContinueWith on the task returned from the ModelWrapper

```
public void GetStuff()
{
    modelWrapper.GetStuff().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (!task.IsFaulted)
        {
            // we got our stuff!!
            Stuff stuff = task.Result;
        }
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

ModelWrapper - Wraps the call to the Model in a task

```
public Task<Stuff> GetStuff()
{
    var task = Task<Stuff>.Run(() =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Starting the task in the ModelWrapper");
        return model.GetStuff();
    });

    return task;
}
```

Model - Makes a call to the server but blocks it.

```
public Stuff GetStuff()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = client.GetAsync("http://localhost/GetStuff").Result;
    return DeserialiseResponse(response);
}
```

As you can see my model is completely synchronous. I know the blocking web service call is not ideal, but this is why I want to migrate it over time.

What I want to do is change my View Model to

```
public async Task GetStuffAsync()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Getting stuff async");
    Stuff stuff = await modelWrapper.GetStuff();
    Debug.WriteLine("Waiting on stuff in the viewModel");
}
```

My worry here is that the blocking web service call in the model will cause a deadlock. I know waiting on anything when using the async await pattern can cause deadlocks but I was wondering whether because this call is wrapped up in a task whether it would cause a problem.

Comment: *Don't* use `.Result` or `.Wait()`. `await` exists so you *don't* have to block, use `ContinueWith` or `Task.Run`. Drop the wrapper class altogether. `HttpClient` *alread* returns a task. Change your model to `async Task<Stuff>` and use `var response=await client.GetAsync();`

Comment: Probebly [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270633/avoid-async-from-spreading-in-method-signatures/44276699#44276699 will help you out

Comment: Hi Patagiotis Kanavos, I i know what I am doing is not ideal, but I have to manage the change overtime, so this is why I am asking whether the "halfway house" approach outlined in my query would work.

Comment: There's no "halfway". It's the extra code itself that causes the problem. All you have to do is *delete* the unnecessary code. What you are doing now is taking a running task, blocking it then wrapping it in another running task, then blocking again. Never mind the *waste* of threads, how can you make sense of all this?

Comment: Just change your view to `public async Task  GetStuff(){ var stuff=await model.GetStuffAsync();}`. Change your model method to `public async Task<Stuff> GetStuff()
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost/GetStuff");
    return DeserialiseResponse(response);} 
}`. Arguing about it takes longer than actually deleting the unnecessary code

Comment: What I should say is that model is used by other view models so the async pattern will spread throughout my codebase. This will increase the testing needed to be performed. I need to manage the time/effort/cost.

Comment: Then you should read the previous comment again. Arguing about it will take longer than making the change. Using *broken* code just to make tests pass isn't a great idea either. Use `.Result` or `.Wait()` in any tests you can't make asynchronous. NUnit works just fine with asyn tests though

Comment: OK Thanks Panagiotis. The original question is whether the approach I have outlined above will cause deadlocks. Does anyone know?